# Is self recursion possible in arrow function?

Tags: typescript

```
   private recursiveFunction(node: any): boolean {
    var returnVal: boolean = false;
    if (node.name('ABC') !== -1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (node.children) {
        for (let child of node.children) {
            if (this.recursiveFunction(child)) {
                returnVal = true;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Can I write this function as arrow function? Not sure if this is at all supported in javascript/typescript.

**Edit**
I want to pass this function as arrow function in filter method of Array. For example

```
    let resultArray = someArray.filter((item: any) => {
        return item.hasValue();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

```
var recursiveFunction = (node: any): boolean => {
    var returnVal: boolean = false;
    if (node.name('ABC') !== -1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (node.children) {
        for (let child of node.children) {
            if (recursiveFunction(child)) {
                returnVal = true;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make it more obvious. What's the exact problem? You can bind the arrow function to a local variable and pass it to the filter function. If you want to know if it works without that step: No, since how could you call to a function that has no name.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you meant then how about:

```
let fn = (node: any) => {
    if (node.name('ABC') !== -1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (node.children) {
        return node.children.some(kid => fn(kid));
    }

    return node.hasValue();
};

let resultArray = someArray.filter(fn);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20fn%20%3D%20(node%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(node.name('ABC')%20!%3D%3D%20-1)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(node.children)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20node.children.some(kid%20%3D%3E%20fn(kid))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20node.hasValue()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20resultArray%20%3D%20%5B%5D.filter(fn)%3B))